# Ubuntu 16.04: I cleared PATH in .profile - now I can neither login, nor fix .profile from recovery. Is there a way I to not load .profile at startup?

Tags: 16.04, encryption, recovery-mode

So I've already looked at the guide that asked me to just change `~/.profile` from recovery, but unfortunately I cannot do that since my home directory is encrypted and when I try to decrypt it from root recovery, I just get the message that my

```
encrypted private directory is not set up properly
```

I really appreciate any help be it getting access to my encrypted home directory or forcing `~/.profile` to not load at startup.

Comment: One possible workaround might be to change your user's login shell to one that doesn't read .profile (`tcsh` for example - in fact pretty much any `csh` - or `zsh`) - you should be able to do so from recovery mode (after remounting the root filesytem in read-write mode) using `chsh`

Comment: @steeldriver Thank you so much for your help! I ran 'sudo apt-get install tcsh' & 'chsh -s /bin/tcsh chaoscrasher' from recovery, I still get the same problem on login. Anything I'm doing wrong?

Comment: @steeldriver I actually was able to login with a x2go connection & fix the problem, so I guess that's nice.

Comment: Perhaps you would consider adding that as an answer (explaining the steps)?

Comment: Well, it's only useful if you happen to have an x2go server running when this happens, so this would be a very special case solution. Should I still add it?